# Windows Services / .net environment

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows

We are planning to upgrade to windows server 2008 machine (from server 2003) and have a bunch of windows services written in visual studio 2003/2005 that we will have to migrate.  My concerns is that on server 2008 there is no .NET 1.1 framework, as we had on the server 2003.

I have some doubts, but hopeful to clear them here:

1. Are windows services 'targeted' for specific .net environments?
2. If, yes, how can I migrate to framework to 2.0?
3. Can I use the installutil from .net 2.2 to install a .net 1.1 win service?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1. Are windows services 'targeted' for specific .net environments?

Not specifically. .NET assemblies are version specific, but usually backwards compatible. A .NET 1.1 assembly will still run on a 2.0 or higher .NET version. I do suggest to upgrade though since .NET 1.1 is more than ten years old already.

> 2. If, yes, how can I migrate to framework to 2.0?

You have to change the targeted .NET Framework for the Visual Studio project. You can do this in the Project Settings dialog. You have to recompile and distribute that newer version.

> 3. Can I use the installutil from .net 2.2 to install a .net 1.1 win service?

Yes. The `installutil` is not something .NET specific. It will work for any exe as far as I know.

Comment: In Visual Studio 2003 I cannot see where to change the .NET version.  Does it mean that I will have to migrate the solution to visual studio 2005/2008 first then change to .NET 2.0?

Comment: @Vikash: Yes, you should. That version supports .NET 2.0. Or move to 2013 directly.

Answer (score 0):

You can install .NET 1.1 (and also a SP1) on Windows 2008.  It warns you about conflicts but works ok.

Comment: The IT guys won't do that, they are just requesting the dev team to upgrade the apps...

Comment: @Vikash as they should.

Comment: @Patrick exactly, .NET 1.1 is 12 years old. Upgrade your projects.